# kitchen not detecting vagrant plugin `kitchen-vagrant`

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen

Ubuntu 14.10 fresh install

```
chef@ubuntu:~/db2$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

chef@ubuntu:~/db2$ vagrant -v 
Vagrant 1.4.3
chef@ubuntu:~/db2$ vagrant plugin list
kitchen-vagrant (0.15.0)
chef@ubuntu:~/db2$ chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.4.0
chef@ubuntu:~/db2$ 

chef@ubuntu:~/db2$ kitchen converge --parallel
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.3.1)
-----> Creating <default-centos-511>...
-----> Creating <default-fedora-20>...
The plugin "kitchen-vagrant" could not be found. Please make sure that it is
properly installed via `vagrant plugin`. Note that plugins made for
Vagrant 1.0.x are not compatible with 1.1+ and this error will likely
continue to show when you use `plugin install` with a 1.0.x plugin.
```

`chef gem list` indicates that kitchen-vagrant is also installed:

```
io-console (0.4.2)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
json (1.8.2, 1.8.1)
kitchen-vagrant (0.15.0)
knife-spork (1.5.0)
libyajl2 (1.2.0)
....
```

Why does kitchen not detect the vagrant plugin kitchen-vagrant even though it's listed as installed?

Comment: Does `chef gem list` have the `kitchen-vagrant` installed?

Comment: can you post the output of chef gem env and show us what your $PATH looks like?

Answer (score 1):

As the error states its due to compatibility issue between vagrant version installed and vagrant plugin. To fix the issue install plugin version compatible with vagrant version 1.1x

Answer (score 0):

Chef comes preinstalled with its own ruby version, thus packages, plugin and stuff.

there is a possibility:

- that you have installed the Kitchen-vagrant plugin on **System Ruby**
- whereas the `kitchen converge` calls the plugin from the Chef ruby and thus can't find it in its Gem Path.

Try `chef gem list` as mentioned by Arthur to find out if the plugin is installed in the chef ruby version.